# How do I read and separate the first portion of the array from the rest?

Tags: c#, arrays, file, split

So I have a minor problem with my code and am almost certain that it should be an easy fix. So I have some data that I have in a file that reads:

```
25 150
60
63
61
70
72
68
66
68
70
```

The problem with this bit of data is that the first line: "25 150", are suppose to be saved as integers so that I can use them throughout the code. I have the problem solved without that line of numbers because the array can separate them as it normally does. How do I write the code so that it separates those two numbers and saves them as two different integers? This is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace proj11LEA
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SIZE = 50;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] volts = new int[SIZE];

            string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";

            Console.WriteLine("\nResistor Batch Test Analysis Program\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Data file must be in your Documents folder.");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the file name: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            string path = environment + input;

            StreamReader data = new StreamReader(path);
            string fromFile;
            int count = 0;
            int start = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("\nRes#\tDissipation\tPassed");

            do
            {
                fromFile = data.ReadLine();
                if (fromFile != null)
                {
                    string[] dataArray = fromFile.Split();
                    volts[count] = int.Parse(dataArray[0]);
                    count++;
                }
            } while (fromFile != null);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                int diss = (volts[i] * volts[i])/25;
                if (diss >= 150)
                {
                    string answer = ("yes");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1:d2}\t\t{2}", start++, diss , answer);
                }
                else
                {
                    string answer = ("no");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1:d2}\t\t{2}", start++, diss, answer);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear - you have all those numbers in a file, and you want to take the first line and create two integers of them? What does your current code do?

Answer (score 0):

this will create a list of int from a text file of numbers like you have, then you can manipulate it how you need!

```
   List<int> data = new List<int>();

        using (StreamReader xReader = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            while (!xReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = xReader.ReadLine();
                string[] input = line.Split(' ', '\r');// this splits the line on the space and newline
                foreach (string item in input)
                {
                    data.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
                }
            }
        }
```